# Security and Mail-Enabled Security Groups in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-permissions

I've done my best to Google this one and am hitting a wall.  Our Org has widely used Mail-Enabled Security and Security groups via O365 to apply permissions to our SharePoint Online instance.  The groups are many, and wide ranging in terms of what they touch. For clarity, these are NOT SharePoint Online groups at the site level, these are the mail-enabled security & security groups generated in the O365 admin portal.

I was recently asked to do something that in theory sounds quite simple, however I'm not savvy enough in Powershell to script out something like this myself. Is there a way to view what sites, libraries, documents, etc. a mail-enabled security or security group has access to across a SharePoint site collection?  The thought of having to go through each site individually and check to see what groups have access to what is daunting and we'd love to avoid using a 3rd party application if at all possible. Ultimately we want kill one of the groups off and replace it with another, but we are totally unsure what access the former has.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

So far, 3rd-party is your best friend if you want to generate a permission report from SharePoint Online. One of the best 3rd-party so far is Sharegate Desktop (in my opinion).

You can try this PowerShell script anyway, to generate all the permissions regardless of users or security groups set as which permission level in SharePoint.

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/09/sharepoint-online-user-permissions-audit-report-using-pnp-powershell.html

*If you feel that this answer is helpful, please take time to set this reply as answer to help anyone else too.*